# Suggestions for an app to help me memorize a large amount of information which I'll need to know for my exams

Tags: android, educational, flashcard

I am preparing for competitive examinations where I have to cram up a lot of data. Dates, events, who's who, technical terms, etc. So its necessary for me to keep revising them in a planned manner.

Until now, I would write down the terms on a notepad and review them when I get the time. But the problem is that, as the number of terms increase, it's tough to review each term equally. The ones jotted down at the beginning are revised more often and some in the middle are missed completely.

Therefore, I was looking for a software where I could feed the terms/data and when run it would pop up the least reviewed terms one by one. Basically, similar to the vocabulary building apps out there but in this one I will be feeding in the terms.

Also, it would be really nice if the application was on Android.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Did I get it right: You look for a tool that you can type in information and that tests you on that information so that each piece is shown equally often? So, Step1: Enter question Step2: Enter correct answer Step3: Request one of the questions and see if you get it right.

Comment: Google for "flashcard". Even the first few hits will help you

Comment: @AngeloFuchs Yes... You got everything right :)

Comment: You might want to try some spaced-repetition software.  If I understand correctly how such software works, the more often you forget a piece of information, the more often you'll see the flashcard with that information on it.  You can get free spaced-repetition software for Windows, Android, iOS, and other platforms.  Or you can do spaced repetition online (but note that the supermemo.net Web app will usually delete your account after 100 days of inactivity).

Comment: To find some spaced-repetition software that you can download, simply do a Web search for [ spaced repetition ].  I've never used any flashcard or spaced-repetition software of any sort, so I can't make recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [Pauker](http://pauker.sourceforge.net/) an open-source no-cost learning application that does what you want.
There is also [Mini-Pauker](http://pauker.sourceforge.net/pauker.php?target=home&lang=en&project=minipauker) for mobile phones, but I tested Pauker on my desktop.

Its quite easy, you open the program, then you have the "add new cards" button, you enter the question or queue or whatever on the front side (left) and the answer on the back side (right).

You can select if you want to remember it through reading it or through typing it.

This is the screen shot of Pauker in German:
[image: Pauker Screenshot]

There is a library of available cards on the Pauker home page. As the name indicates (Pauker is the person doing the "cramming in" in German) the tool was written by a German, while there are translations to various other languages, the available cards on the home page looked like its only in German.

Pauker is available on the Debian appstore (aptitude) so most common Linuxes will have it available. It is written in Java and thus platform independent, for details check out the website.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @unforgettableid in the comments section, I went through some spaced-repetition software and found [ANKI](https://apps.ankiweb.net/) to be the best suited for my needs.

Clean interface, powerful (supports Latex) and has a helpful community. It is available on almost all popular platforms. It might take a little time to get used to its interface, but once you get over the initial hurdles, Anki will pretty much handle revision sessions for you. They also have publically shared flash cards for [common stuff like languages and maths](https://ankiweb.net/shared/decks/), so you can also get a head start. :)

I realize that I am two years late in posting an answer, but I hope somebody would benefit from this.